# How to get data from custom ListView to use in Activity?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm working on a custom `ListView` with a custom `ListAdapter` based on `BasedAdapter`. My `ListView` item has a `ToggleButton` and an `EditText`. In the activity that uses this `ListView`, I have a `Button` called `Save`. When I click `Save`, the activity must find someway to get data from `ListView` to do some stuffs with this.

In the custom `ListView` adapter, I use an `ArrayList` to keep track change in `DataItem`, with represents the model for the `ListView` item (contains a `boolean` variable for the `ToggleButton` and a `String` for the text in `EditText`).
The problem is that when I click `Save`, I must, somehow, get the data from the `ArrayList` from the adapter, which also consists of updated data of `EditText` and `ToggleButton` in each list item?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you would be the one setting this Adapter into the ListView.  All you need to do is save the instance of this adapter in a member variable in the Activity.  Adapter already provides methods for accessing individual items.  You can add more methods to get to your data.  Something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List data;
    ......

    public boolean[] getCheckStates() {
        //get values of your checkboxes here
    }

    public String[] getTexts() {
        //get text of your text boxes here
    }

    // implement all other methods of BaseAdapter
}
```

And then in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        .....
        adapter = new MyAdapter(...);
        ...
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                boolean[] checks = adapter.getCheckStates();
                String[] texts = adapter.getTexts();
                ....
            }
        });
    }

    ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is what u need:

```
public class MusicTrack extends Activity {  
private ArrayAdapter<CardDetails> listAdapter ;  
ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();  
CardDetailsAdapter mListAdapter;  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    final ArrayList<CardDetails> cardResults = GetCardDetails();
    for (int i = 0; i < cardResults.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("card redsults: " + cardResults.get(i).isSelected());
    }
    final ListView welcomelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.welcomelistID);

    listAdapter = new CardDetailsAdapter(this, cardResults);
    welcomelist.setAdapter(listAdapter );      

    final Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveID);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the checkbox status and save related details into database
        //  Intent intent = new Intent(MusicTrack.this, TransactionSummaryActivity.class);
            itemChecked = mListAdapter.itemChecked1;    
            System.out.println("item checked: " + itemChecked);

            for (int i = 0; i < cardResults.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("cardResults and checked status: " + cardResults.get(i).getText());
                System.out.println("cardResults and checked status111: " + cardResults.get(i).isSelected());
            }
        }
    });

}
private ArrayList<CardDetails> GetCardDetails() {

    ArrayList<CardDetails> carddetailresults = new ArrayList<CardDetails>();
    CardDetails sr1 = new CardDetails();

      sr1.setText("Text1"); 
      sr1.setSelected(false);
      carddetailresults.add(sr1);

      sr1 = new CardDetails();
      sr1.setText("Text2"); 
      sr1.setSelected(true);
      carddetailresults.add(sr1);

      sr1 = new CardDetails();
      sr1.setText("Text3"); 
      sr1.setSelected(true);
      carddetailresults.add(sr1);

      sr1 = new CardDetails();
      sr1.setText("Text4"); 
      sr1.setSelected(true);
      carddetailresults.add(sr1);

      sr1 = new CardDetails();
      sr1.setText("Text5"); 
      sr1.setSelected(false);
      carddetailresults.add(sr1);

    return carddetailresults;
}}
class CardDetails{   
String text;   
Boolean selected;   
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String bankName) {
    text = bankName;
}

 public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }}


class CardDetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CardDetails> {
private static ArrayList<CardDetails> searchArrayList;
public static ArrayList<Integer> alSelCards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked1 = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

protected Context getContext;
 public CardDetailsAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<CardDetails> results) {
      super( context, R.layout.webview, R.id.textID, results );
      // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
      searchArrayList = results;
      getContext = context;
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
      itemChecked1 = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            itemChecked1.add(i, results.get(i).isSelected()); // initializes all items value with

        }
    }

public int getCount() {
    if (searchArrayList != null)
        return searchArrayList.size();
    return 0;
}

public CardDetails getItem(int position) {

    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    CardDetails planet = (CardDetails) this.getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textID);
            holder.chkbox = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.togID);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.text.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getText());
            holder.chkbox.setTag(planet);
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(planet.isSelected());

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.chkbox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
            holder.text = viewHolder.getText();

            holder.text.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getText());
            holder.chkbox.setTag(planet);

            holder.chkbox.setChecked(planet.isSelected());

        }
        holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ToggleButton cb = (ToggleButton) v;
                CardDetails planet = (CardDetails) cb.getTag();
                //planet.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                if (holder.chkbox.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked1.set(position, true);
                    holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
                    planet.setSelected(true);


                } else if (!holder.chkbox.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked1.set(position, false);
                    holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);
                    planet.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private ToggleButton chkbox;
        TextView text;

        public ViewHolder() {
        }

        public ViewHolder(TextView text, ToggleButton chkbox) {
            this.chkbox = chkbox;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public ToggleButton getCheckBox() {
            return chkbox;
        }

        public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
            this.chkbox = chkbox;
        }

        public TextView getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(TextView text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

    }}
```

import required things

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank for your support, it's very nice of you. In your adapter, you pre-set you EditText' text values. That's ok in my first time loaded. But my problem when user change the text in the EditText ( in each ListView item). I must update back this new entered-text to the ArrayList (corresponding to the position of item in ListView) in Adapter that stores information. I try "onFocusChanged" event of EditText. But there's more problems arised. ( maybe I will ask them in another post).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats correct.
Also, to get radioButton checkedId you ned to create a onCkeckedChangeListener and set the checkedId there. After that override following method

```
public int[] getChkId() {
        return chkId;
    }
```

to get the checked radio Button.
Thanks.